# FindControl TextBox which don't get the good value Sharepoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In my asp page i got :

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList ID="_SCP_ddlStatutDelais" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:TextBox ID="_SCP_tbTypeMiseProduction" Rows="3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="_btSend" runat="server" Text="Envoyer" CssClass="ms-ButtonHeightWidth"
                                    onclick="_btSend_Click"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Then, in my code behind, i get values from database to provide my TextBox and DDL in my Page_Load, and it works.

Then, i want to update my database with values modify by user, so i try to get the Text in TextBox but i can only got the Text that i put from my database, and myTextBox.Text ignore Text modify by user.

Code Behind :

```
protected void _btSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Control context = this.Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderMain");
//Informations Database Connection etc...
reflector.Set(d[fieldtomap],rootTypeDescriptor, ref instance, ((TextBox)(context.FindControl(nodeName))).Text);
//Submit update to database
}
```

For example if i get from my database : "Test", i put in my TextBox "Test". Then user modify this value then validate with the button, ((TextBox)(context.FindControl(nodeName))).Text contains always "Test" and ignore user's modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking for Page.IsPostback when binding your data?  You should only be binding on the initial page load, else, the change are overwritten - just like you are experiencing.